# How to configure dns in centos to resolve internal lan ip

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, nat

i have a router with nat to web server inside LAN. Also i have internal DNS server on centos. When i try to access web server from internet it works fine, but when i try to access from the LAN, DNS returns public ip and cannot access to web server.
How must i confgure named DNS server to avoid this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router, if configured properly should allow lan clients to see lan content properly NAT'd from the public IP.

We'll need to know what DNS server you are asking about.

You're after split horizon DNS. There is more information on the web about the topic than anyone could shack a stick at.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bind9-named-configure-views/

Comment: The router is configured properly and works fine from wan to lan.

Comment: Problem solved by creating two files for diferent zones. So now i can resolve public ip from WAN and redirected to my server with router NAT. In the other way, i resolve private ip from LAN and have direct access to my server without envolving router. In DHCP i have my DNS server as primary and public one as secondary. This is the way i can access the server with the same domain name from wan or lan.